# How to make NSTableView column fit its content on resize?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn

Im my app I have NSTableView (view based) and when I add the value that is too long to the last column

first it "hits" the scroller

[image]

then when I resize the window the row is not getting resized to fit the content

[image]

does anyone know how to deal with this problem?!

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: make sure TableCellView autosizing is set horizontally to expand

Comment: If you mean Autoresizing box in NIB...it is check marked

Comment: Did you figure out an answer for this? I have the same issue

Comment: nope, didn't solve this one yet

Comment: I solved the issue. I am not sure if you have the same problem but if you are using NSTableCellView under NSTableColumn, then you need to set constraints for NSTableCellView. Highlight NSTableCellView and click on "Resolve Auto-layout issue" and click on "Add missing constraints in the container". This will fix the issue if its same as mine.

Comment: Cool, let me put this as answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this problem is due to constraints. If you are using NSTableCellView under NSTableColumn, then you need to set constraints for NSTableCellView. Highlight NSTableCellView and click on "Resolve Auto-layout issue" and click on "Add missing constraints in the container". This will fix the issue.

Comment: More specifically, the table cell view needs constraints that keep its size pinned to its container's size.